# i cannot convert the data type of one column from object to int or float in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have been learning data analysis and visualization using Python but I am having trouble on changing datatypes of certain dataframe components from one form to another
In this code snippet I want to change the fractional data to integer
I need to change the RottenTomatoes and IMDb to integer or float so that I can use visualization models and convert the fractional data to integer
[screenshot of the dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyEev.png)

I tried to convert them using the following code:

```
movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'] = movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'].fillna(0/100).astype('int')
```

The following error was called:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100/100'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to extract the numerator of those fractions and convert it into an int (or a float).

If this is the case, to convert into `int` you can:

```
>>> int(('95/100').split('/')[0])
95
```

In pandas, this will become:

```py
movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'] = movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'].fillna('0/100').apply(lambda x: int((x).split('/')[0]))
```

Bear in mind that you should also change your `.fillna`, so that the value is a string (`0/100` is a float).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'] = movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'].fillna('0/100').apply(eval)

# or

import ast

movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'] = movieRatings['RottenTomatoes'].fillna('0/100').apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

```
   RottenTomatoes
0            0.99
1            0.96
2            0.00
```

Comment: i followed the earlier comment and it worked thank you for your help